Delay time measuring ESP32
I have a audio processing project with esp32:
mic(in) -> adc(external, pcm1808) -> esp32(filters, effects process) -> dac(external, pcm5102a) -> dynamic(out)
I wonder how can I measure a delay time for this scheme. I think that I can release the ADC and just calculate the delay for the chain:
internal esp32 sinus generator -> filters, effect process -> dac(external, pcm5102a). How can I do this?

What about eg a 2-channel signal analyzer measuring both the input and output, have your system just output the signal as-is, and then look at the analyzer's output to compute the delay?

To measure the delay time for your signal processing chain on an ESP32, you can use a GPIO pin to toggle at specific points in the chain and measure the time difference between these toggles using an oscilloscope or logic analyzer
Example :
If you are using an external ADC and DAC , you would place the GPIO toggles around the ADC read and DAC write functions in your code.
Here is an example code of how you can integrate this with an I2S-based ADC and DAC for the Arduino Framework :
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <driver/i2s.h>

const int startPin = 2;
const int endPin = 4;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  pinMode(startPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(endPin, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(startPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(endPin, LOW);

  // Configure I2S for ADC  and DAC 
  i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
    .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX | I2S_MODE_RX),
    .sample_rate = 44100,
    .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
    .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB,
    .intr_alloc_flags = 0,
    .dma_buf_count = 8,
    .dma_buf_len = 64,
    .use_apll = false,
    .tx_desc_auto_clear = true,
    .fixed_mclk = 0
  };

  i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
    .bck_io_num = 26,
    .ws_io_num = 25,
    .data_out_num = 22,
    .data_in_num = 23
  };

  i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
  i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
  i2s_set_clk(I2S_NUM_0, 44100, I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT, I2S_CHANNEL_STEREO);
}

void loop() {
  size_t bytesRead, bytesWritten;
  int16_t i2s_read_buffer[64];
  int16_t i2s_write_buffer[64];

  // Toggle start pin before reading from ADC
  digitalWrite(startPin, HIGH);

  // Read data from ADC
  i2s_read(I2S_NUM_0, (char *)i2s_read_buffer, sizeof(i2s_read_buffer), &bytesRead, portMAX_DELAY);

  // Signal processing code (replace with actual processing)
  // For example: applying filters/effects
  for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead / 2; i++) {
    i2s_write_buffer[i] = i2s_read_buffer[i];  // Simple pass-through
  }

  // Toggle end pin after writing to DAC
  digitalWrite(endPin, HIGH);

  // Write data to DAC
  i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, (char *)i2s_write_buffer, bytesRead, &bytesWritten, portMAX_DELAY);

  // Reset GPIO pins to LOW
  digitalWrite(startPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(endPin, LOW);

  // Add a delay before next iteration (for example purposes)
  delay(1000);
}



OP never said they're using Arduino. This also doesn't measure processing delay for any given signal.

Its just an example using Arduino framework, You can add a millis()-like function using timers in any framework even in barematel code

And how would you measure the latency of a signal chain like OP's with this approach?

To measure the delay time for your signal processing chain on an ESP32, you can use a GPIO pin to toggle at specific points in the chain and measure the time difference between these toggles using an oscilloscope or logic analyzer

Right, that's not this approach.

I have modified code for example : how you can integrate this with an I2S-based ADC and DAC. Please check
